# How to open a file located in a non-sdcard directory in Tasker?

Tags: tasker

How can one open a file located in a subfolder of the rootfolder, using tasker, in LineageOS 14.1?

My attempts so far have been to:

1. Create a new task in tasker.
2. Check if tasker has root permission with variable named "root available": `%ROOT`. This returns `yes`. Therefore, I assume Tasker has root permission.
3. create the action: "open file"
4. This only allows the accessing the `/storage/` of either the internal or external drive.
5. Therefore, I manually entered the path to the file located in the rootfolder I am trying to access as: `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` and ran the task, but it returns the error: `file not found`.

   [image: IMG:]
   [image: IMG:]
6. So I tried `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` and ran the task, but it returns the same error.
7. I tried to open the file with fdroid's app: `editor`, without opening a file explorer to open the file. But I am unable to pass the file location as an argument to the app `editor` when I create a task to do it.

Comment: I do not not anything about tasker but I do know about shell commands. If that is what tasker is using the problem is you just need to cd into the directory example:  `cd /data/misc/wifi/` to add another command `&&` or `;`should do the trick example :  `cd /data/misc/wifi/ && your command` or `cd /data/misc/wifi/; your command` depending on how you the commmand to follow through.

Comment: @BoLawson if it's a *shell command*, one simply has to prefix it with `!` to tell Tasker to perfrom it with root powers AFAIR (could be that meanwhile there's a check-box for that). However, I don't know if there's an equivalent for opening a file.

Comment: Good point @Izzy, also to open the file the `nano` command should do the trick looking like `!nano /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` if it comes back with the unknown file/directory error then cd into the directory. On first comment put `!` in front of the cd.

Comment: @BoLawson I've missed the editor part. Indeed I'm not sure if a non-root editor app (OP wanted to use a specific one) could work. nano or vi should do fine.

Comment: @BoLawson thank you for the suggestion, at first instant I indeed tried checking if I could execute the command from Termux on android and used `cd /data/misc/wifi/` to browse to the directory, verified the file existance using `ls`. But then got stuck on how to open the file from Termux. https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Sharing_Data suggested `termux-open wpa_supplicant.conf` but I was unable to use or install `termux-open` from Termux. I did not try nano yet, as I will not be able to access Termux/terminal in ordinary use. I will look into that, thank you!

Comment: I don't think [Editor](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.billthefarmer.editor/) app would work even with a right argument. I tried to load a non-sdcard file in it within itself and it simply failed to load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inbuilt Open File action doesn't seem to work for non-`/storage` file paths because it is hardcoded (I presumed from its error logs) to only load a file located under `/storage/emulated/0`. Even if you mention the absolute location using `file://`, it would still append `/storage/emulated/0` to the file path and throw an error.

Because Open File action simply sends an intent, we can do that manually ourselves. The Send Intent action is pretty good for this, except it also fails with non-`/sdcard` file paths. Tasker implements [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) (a way to securely share files with other apps). The action could work but Tasker's manifest file provisions for not exporting the file provider, which means other apps cannot make use of it. Since Tasker converts even absolute file path (with file://) into a file provider URI, there is no way out for us to load a non-`/sdcard` file using that action too,  except to ask Tasker's developer to fix this, or the user themselves tweaks the manifest file.

The solution, however, is available using command-line. Use the action:

Code → Run Shell:

- Command:

  ```
  am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "file://FILE_PATH" -t "text/plain" -f 0x13000000 -n android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity
  ```

  `file://` is intended as is. In your case, the file path should be `file:///data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

  `text/plain` can be replaced with `text/*` too if you don't know your file's mime-type.

  (You can know about `am` [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#am).) I don't know what that flag (0x13000000) does in particular.
- tick Use Root

Running the task would now give you the bottom sheet with all the apps which can load a file with mime-type `text/plain`. However, when testing  this, only [QuickEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.edit) app was able to load that file successfully, so I recommend using it unless you get this working with an another editor.

Comment: Nice, I installed tasker to test it out and it works +1 good stuff

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86862/discussion-on-answer-by-firelord-how-to-open-a-file-located-in-a-non-sdcard-dire).

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate explanation. I can confirm the described steps with command `am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "file://file:///data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf" -t "text/plain" -f 0x13000000 -n android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity` work in Tasker V5.2.bf1. Indeed the only text editor I could get it to work, currently is QuickEdit as you mentioned.